# Tag having a parameter as tagid in URL

Tags: tags, kentico

I am using following tranformation for displaying all tags a page is tagged with.

{% IfEmpty(DocumentTags,"","Tags: " + GetDocumentTags(DocumentTagGroupID, DocumentTags, "~/somepage")) #%}

This is currently creating a URL with a parameter of tagname. I would like to modify a parameter and changed it to have a tagid as parameter as my repetaer webpart takes a tagid as a parameter . How  can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to pass in the DocumentID to provider

```
TagInfoProvider.GetTags(id)
```

Then just look through those and generate your links.